# Sqlite Finalize statement failing

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Error: sqlite3_finalize failed (database is locked). I have released memory also properly in each view. Has anyone faced this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Database is locked" means that (duh!) the database is locked.  Some other sqlite operation against the database is still "pending", possibly because you failed to finalize an earlier query, or possibly because there's a query going on in an async thread.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're hitting some legacy cruft in the SQLite interface. To summarize, when you `sqlite3_step` and the result is an error, `slite3_finalize` will return the same error. Pay attention to the error from `sqlite3_step` and other SQLite calls, and ignore the error from `slite3_finalize`.

Per SQLite documentation for `sqlite3_finalize`:

> If the most recent evaluation of the statement encountered no errors or or if the statement is never been evaluated, then `sqlite3_finalize()` returns `SQLITE_OK`.  If the most recent evaluation of statement S failed, then `sqlite3_finalize(S)` returns the appropriate error code or extended error code.

It talks about the most recent evaluation of the statement **rather than the finalize itself**. This is nowhere near explicit enough, but there's another comment in the documentation that is:

> **Goofy Interface Alert:** In the legacy interface, the `sqlite3_step()` API always returns a generic error code, `SQLITE_ERROR`, following any error other than `SQLITE_BUSY` and `SQLITE_MISUSE`.  You must call `sqlite3_reset()` or `sqlite3_finalize()` in order to find one of the specific error codes that better describes the error.

It goes on to say this is fixed by the v2 APIs, but I think that's only partially correct. When using the v2 APIs, `sqlite3_step` returns an error code directly. However, there's no `sqlite3_finalize_v2`. And in my testing, **`sqlite3_finalize` continues to return the error code from `sqlite3_step`**.

In other words: Ignore the error from `sqlite3_finalize`. Pay attention to the error you're almost certainly getting but ignoring from `sqlite3_step`.

Comment: This summary is a *lot* more helpful than the accepted answer. Cheers, Steven!